# Trigger enter keypress not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've searched Stackoverflow for questions similar to what I was looking for. However, all the posts I've looked in didn't help me with what I'm trying to achieve when I'm trying to make the enter key to work. I'm working on a project for FreeCodeCamp and the code is in Codepen. I don't know what's wrong. I only know that it works when I press the button (which is the search icon).

Here's my code in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/evZzzX):

HTML

```
<form>
      <input id="searchkeyword" type="text" placeholder="Search Wikipedia" />
      <i id="submitbtn" class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submitbtn").on("click", getWord);

  $("#searchkeyword").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
    $("#submitbtn").on("click", getWord);
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: it seems to work in your codepen, what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enter keypress within a `<form>`, by default, will submit the form. If you don't want this to happen, you can prevent it by adding `e.preventDefault();`

More importantly, you're not clicking the button on keypress - you're just *re-binding* a click event. It needs to be `$("#submitbtn").click()`, without the `on` portion.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#submitbtn").on("click", getWord); // .on attaches an event to our button

  $("#searchkeyword").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#submitbtn").click(); // .click triggers the .on("click", ... ) event
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: It's fine :) Again thanks so much for your help. I'm studying to become front-end developer and get an awesome job.